# Is there any way to detect whether android camera is real or not?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera

So i need to distinguish the image result from camera. In android emulator there are many ways to emulated the camera like virtual scene, custom image, etc. Is there any way to distinguish it?

Comment: Did u find something about it ?  I`m having the same issue... I need to identify emulated cameras to prevent the inputed image came from another source instead the real camera.